# Hide First Section Header of a TableView Grouped in a UITableViewController - Swift 3 - Xcode8

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

This is my very first post here.
I need to mention I'm not a coder, I'm a UX designer and I'm trying to get fluent with Xcode Storyboard+ to build better prototypes for my fellow Engeneers.

#### The issue

I'm trying to give a "native" look to my profile view.
Right now my profile view is a UITableViewController.

I realized that the "native" look comes with the settings "grouped" applied to the TableView.

Here is how it looks compare to my previous version, not using "grouped"

[image]

As you can see, the grouped version pushed my TableView down because of the header. I haven't entered any text in the Header settings. Yet the space is taken by a fixed margin.

**I want to get rid of that space.**

I've found this code on Stack, that sounded like should be solving my issue.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    let headerHeight: CGFloat

    switch section {
    case 0:
        // hide the header
        headerHeight = CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude
    default:
        headerHeight = 21
    }

    return headerHeight
}
```

I've added this in my ProfileTableViewController.swift inside the super.viewDidLoad().
But the space remains and I am now out of options.

Maybe the problem comes from the header/footer settings and not even the section title... not even sure anymore.

Comment: Try this, implement heightForFooterInSection  and return CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude

Answer (score 4):

The latest two options offered by @Pragnesh are working for me.
I'm not sure shifting the tableview up is the best practice ever, but it does the trick for now.

I'm sure there is still a way to just hide the section header.

I've been using this

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-35, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code in viewDidLoad():

1). In viewDidLoad():

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

2). Either you can write this in viewDidLoad():

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-64, 0, 0, 0)
```

3). Or you can write this:

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, 0, -20, 0);
```

Comment: Did not seemed to change anything, I still have a gap at the top.

Comment: The options 2 and 3 are working great. I've adjusted to -35 that seems to be the exact size of the gap I had.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

In storyboard/xib:

```
 1. Click TableView.
 2. Click on Size Inspector on Right side. 
 3. You will see SectionHeight: Header and Footer.
 4. Make both these values 1. 
 5. It will remove the extra spaces.
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thx. The problem of this method is that it also changes the sizes of all the others headers of my TableView. I only need to get rid of the space at the very top

Comment: It will remove space. Increase height of header for another sections. Make it greater than 21.

Comment: Selecting a Section does not allow to change size individually.

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    let headerHeight: CGFloat

    switch section {
    case 0:
        // hide the header
        headerHeight = CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude
    default:
        headerHeight = 21
    }

    return headerHeight
}

Answer (score 2):

Set 1 as the first section header's height. Then I use the contentInset to hide that height underneath the navigation bar.Given below -

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0)
            return 1.0f;
    return 32.0f;
}

- (NSString*) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        // return some string here ...
    }
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

     self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers work, but I'd rather not mess around with hardcoded insets.
An improvement to @niku solution could be using `CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == 0 {
        return CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude
    }
    // return the height for the other sections
}
```